# For $\boldsymbol{n} \in \mathbb{N}$, does $\boldsymbol{n} \not\in \boldsymbol{n}$ rely on the Axiom of Regularity?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

From the axiom of regularity:

> \begin{equation}
> \left(\forall x\right)\left(x \neq \emptyset \longrightarrow \left(\exists y \in x\right)\left(y \cap x = \emptyset\right)\right),
> \end{equation}

we are able to deduce that $x \not \in x$ for any set $x$ in the ZF language system. Consequently, for every $\boldsymbol{n} \in \mathbb{N}$, we have $\boldsymbol{n} \not \in \boldsymbol{n}$. Is it possible to deduce the same conclusion using only the definition of natural numbers? That is, to deduce $\boldsymbol{n} \not\in \boldsymbol{n}$ using only $\boldsymbol{0} = \emptyset$ and $\boldsymbol{n}^{+} = \boldsymbol{n} \cup \left\{\boldsymbol{n}\right\}$.

Comment: A trivial observation is that if $n \in n$ for some $n \in \mathbb{N}$, then that $n$ is maximal in the sense that $n^+ = n\cup \{n\} = n$.

Comment: Per Wikipedia, the axiom of regularity guarantees that the axiom of infinity actually implies the existence of an infinite set. Though wikipedia isn't always a reliable source on such matters.

Comment: Regularity is definitely not needed. Just prove by induction that if $n<m$, then $n\neq m$. Then $n+1\in n+1$ would imply that $n+1=k$ for some $k\leq n$.

Comment: More general, you could proof $x\notin x$ for every $x$. In this case, i think you need foundation axiom

Comment: @AsafKaragila What do you mean by $n<m$ at this point? Is it $n\subsetneq m$? Seems like you need to prove first that $n\subsetneq m\Leftrightarrow n\in m$ and the only proof of this equivalence I know uses $n\not\in n$.